# Formatting array of object

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, numbers, boolean

I have an array of objects like this

```js
const obj = [{ '1': 'a'},{ '2': 'b'}, {'3': 'c'}]
```

and I want to find like this
`['1','2','3']` and `['a','b','c']`

how to do this?

I have done it but not gotten the result

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```js
const arr = [{ '1': 'a' }, { '2': 'b' }, { '3': 'c' }]

console.log(arr.flatMap((obj) => Object.keys(obj)))
console.log(arr.flatMap((obj) => Object.values(obj)))
```